# Testcocoon exclude macro in C?

Tags: c, testcocoon

Anyone know how to exclude testcocoon run on macro in C.

I have macro as `NOT_USED(x) (if(x) { ; } )`

This is to prevent QAC warnings anyway, but now running testcocoon I want to exclude the coverage calc for the macro. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the part of code you use this macro ?

Comment: There should be no need for obscure macros to begin with. Just type out in your code: `(void)the_variable;`. This is much more readable to C programmers.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer!